# What are these weird booleans used for in JMH?

Tags: java, performance, decompiling, jmh

I wrote [a JMH test](https://github.com/Ray-Eldath/whatever/blob/master/perf/perf.newinst/src/main/java/ray/eldath/whatever/performance/newinst/NewInstPerfTest.java) about the cost of `new` instruction, and checked the class files it generates. Except the usual classes, there're tons of derived classes in `generated` folder:

[image: class files]

This really shocked me, for just few annotations will lead to so many class bounded together through inheritance. I am curious about what things are in those class, so I use a decompile tool (BTW I learned this tool from one talk on KotlinConf 2019) called `procyon` to decompile these generated class, most of them are control related, like measure time (they are explicitly specified can't be inlined) and collect metrics. But there're tons of weird boolean in those class:

[image: a class file consisted of only booleans]

there're many booleans in other generted class files as well. I googled this, and seems they're somewhat derived from [JMH sourse code](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/blob/28d15e9b53c08d99c007f9c7e59e1f238d94b3d4/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/runner/InfraControl.java#L117-L132). So I want to ask what is these booleans used for? I will assume they are closely related to the working principle underlying the JMH... seems no comments about the booleans in JMH source code.

Also, any suggestions about improving the JMH test I mentioned from the very beginning...? I know testing such thing can be very tricky and vulnerable, so I don't know if they are accurate, or reliable enough.

Many thanks.

Comment: You'd probably have to dig deep if you're interested in the JMH internals regarding the booleans. If you don't have the time or interest, then ignore them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guessing.

As you can see, the booleans are private and unused in the source file. They might be used somewhere via reflection, but I'd bet they aren't. So the only thing left is ensuring that `markerBegin` and the other field belong to a different cache in order to prevent [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).

Comment: Many thanks! I think you're right, those inherited booleans are padding for avoid false sharing.

Comment: @RayEldath a JVM could eliminate those, btw. padding is correctly done with `@Contended`.

Comment: @Eugene I don't think so. The fields are visible via reflection; they could be reordered somehow, but this is JMH code and if anyone knows what can happen, it's its author. I guess, JMH predates `@Contended`.

Comment: @maaartinus they should always be visible via reflection, `JIT` could eliminate that, is what I meant. Now I wonder how `@Contended` is really implemented, though.

Comment: One of the famous examples where people failed at this, is [here](https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/08/false-sharing-java-7.html?m=1)

Comment: I _hate_ this 5 min rule of updating a comment, sorry for so many. Yes, I totally agree that Aleksey Shipilev knows better, its just interesting to see such code: he probably knows an internal detail that does not lead to elimination.

Comment: @Eugene I doubt "JIT could eliminate that". There can be a not-yet-loaded class using these fields, even without reflection as they're not private. When this class gets loaded, the JIT would have to replace all instances of the cut-down class by full-blown instances. This would imply relocating everything... something what compacting GCs actually do, but IMHO far too crazy for JIT.

Comment: @Eugene JIT can and does reorder fields... that's why JMH Blackhole uses a [crazy hierarchy](https://github.com/msteindorfer/jmh/blob/master/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/infra/Blackhole.java#L160). No idea how it's supposed to help.....

Comment: Fantastic point about classes that not yet use those fields, I stand corrected.

Comment: As stated in the code comment, this technique relies on a combination of limitations of typical (or a particular) JVM(s). That’s a moving target…