# Flush cache lines in case of a Single Shot benchmark

Tags: java, jvm, jmh

I'd like to run a `SingleShot` JMH benchmark with all cache hierarchy related to the memory working up on are reliably flushed.

The benchmark looks roughly as follows:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class MyBnchmrk {
    public byte buffer[];

    @Setup(Level.Trial)
    public void generateSampleData() throws IOException {
        // writes to buffer ...
    }

    @Setup(Level.Invocation)
    public void flushCaches() {
         //Perfectly I'd like to invoke here something like
         //_mm_clflushopt() intrinsic as in GCC/clang for each line of the buffer
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
    public void benchmarkMemoryBoundCode() {
        //the benchmark
    }
}
```

**Is there a Java way to flush caches before single-shot measurement or hand-written `clflush` is required?**

Comment: A Java way, definitely not. JMH however may provide a mechanism for something like that, so your best bet is to dig into its documentation (and provide an answer if you find it).

Comment: JMH already does a lot stuff to prevent issues with cache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846710/what-are-these-weird-booleans-used-for-in-jmh so probably you don't need anything special here

Answer (score 2):

If you want to measure cache misses access, calling clflush directly is possible from java, but you end up writing JNI library with ASM intrinsic. Not to say, you can't probably do it in a reliable fashion, since you need to provide virtual address, and GC may move you buffer at any time.

Instead I offer you this:

- Use single snapshot benchmark as you do
- Measuring a single opreration would not be a good idea (measuring nanoseconds has high error). Instead create **million of such identical buffers** and do the same operation for million buffers. Every time you access a next buffer, which is not in the cache
- You also can run some calculation between iterations. For example, reading 32+ mb of memory so it evicts cache lines from you cache. But with million of buffers, it doesn't show any profit

The resulting code:

```
    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Fork(value = 1)
public class BufferBenchmarkLatency {

public static final int BATCH_SIZE = 1000000;

public static final int MY_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
public static final int CACHE_LINE_PADDING = 256;

public static class StateHolder extends Padder {
    byte buffer[];

    StateHolder() {
        buffer = new byte[CACHE_LINE_PADDING + MY_BUFFER_SIZE + CACHE_LINE_PADDING];
        Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt());
    }
}

private final StateHolder[] arr = new StateHolder[BATCH_SIZE];
private int index;

@Setup(Level.Trial)
public void setUpTrial() {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = new StateHolder();
    }
    ArrayUtil.shuffle(arr)
}

@Setup(Level.Iteration)
public void prepareForIteration(Blackhole blackhole) {
    index = 0;
    blackhole.consume(CacheUtil.evictCacheLines());
    System.gc();
    System.gc();
}

@Benchmark
public long read() {
    byte[] buffer = arr[index].buffer;
    return buffer[0];
}

@TearDown(Level.Invocation)
public void move() {
    index++;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(BufferBenchmarkLatency.class.getSimpleName())
            .measurementBatchSize(BATCH_SIZE)
            .warmupBatchSize(BATCH_SIZE)
            .measurementIterations(10)
            .warmupIterations(10)
            .build();
    new Runner(opt).run();
}
}
```

As you see, I padd state holder itself, so reading buffer references are always on the different cache lines (Padder class has 24 long fields). Oh, and I also padd buffer itself, JMH won't do it for you.

I've implemented this idea, and I have avg 100 ns result for simple operation like reading first element of the buffer. To read first element you need to read two cache lines (buffer reference + first element). The full code is [here](https://github.com/0xaa4eb/java-benchmarks/tree/master/latency/src/main/java/com/chibik/perf/cpu)